# Bar chart showing mean values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've some financial panel data for disaster relief and have created some bar charts showing the amount of funding per disaster category using this code:

```
    ggplot(Template.2006.2017, aes(x=Disaster_category, y=Total_US_required)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightblue") + 
coord_flip()
```

Now I want to create a similar graph showing the mean instead of the total amount ignoring all the NA:s. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Here's my data (compressed):

```
    structure(list(Disaster_category = structure(c(1L, 15L, 17L, 
15L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 7L, 
2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 
15L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 15L, 8L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 
8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 
2L, 15L, 15L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 2L, 15L, 
8L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 
8L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 
8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 
8L, 15L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 
15L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("", " ", "Disease", "Disease related disaster", 
"Drought", "Drought & storm", "Extreme temperature / fire", "Flood", 
"Flood & drought", "Insect infestation", "Insect infestation & drought", 
"Landslide & flood", "Landslide / mudslide", "Other", "Storm", 
"Storm & flood", "Winter"), class = "factor"), Total_US_received_from.CERF = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 678307.8333, 
678307.8333, 678307.8333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1110469.5, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1905355, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2493246, 
2493246, 2493246, 2493246, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 333333.3333, 333333.3333, 333333.3333, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9365420, 
NA, NA, 14321419, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Total_US_received = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15507224.5, 15507224.5, 15507224.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 333333.3333, 333333.3333, 
    333333.3333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Total_US_required = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 20502064.83, 20502064.83, 20502064.83, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3070192, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 49955895.25, 49955895.25, 49955895.25, 49955895.25, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 333333.3333, 
    333333.3333, 333333.3333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you can use `dput(head(YourDataSet,10))` to get only 10 rows. please edit your question with proper dataset

Comment: I agree with both comments. A small word to the intention of visualising means with bar charts - this is highly misleading and I would not recommend that. Bar charts suggest a *count* of something. A *mean* is a single value with a statistic - I would recommend using either box plots, or dots with error bars instead.

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara: the first 10 rows are all NA:s for the relevant variable. I', not sure that I can compress it much more and keep the data meaningful.

Comment: do a `dt<-na.omit(dt)` it removes all the rows with `NA`, and then run `dput`